# tagging module in python

Tags: python

In python 2.4  how to install the module tagging can any one give me links to it..I am trying to implement a blog system and in the models of which i require this module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fed `django` and `tagging` into a well-known search engine and got the following as the top hit:

http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/

Since most of your "blog" questions are related to Django, I presume that you meant that, rather than Python. It's written in Python, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit) is the currently suggested/most popular Django tagging library. It's maintained by Alex Gaynor, one of the Django core developers.